# HTTPS via HttpClient during a Service failing on gingerbread

Tags: android, httpclient

I've got a strange problem ...

My service that uses HTTPS via HttpClient almost always fails on Gingerbread when the screen is turned off *and* USB/power disconnected. The error is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

Never saw this behaviour with Froyo or older, and of course can't repro in emulator as can't disconnect power or turn off screen.

Also, seems to be only failing when using mobile data.  Wifi (set to always on) seems to work fine.

My phone is a CyanogenMod7/HTC Hero.  This is the only gingerbread I have available to test on.  Works fine on friends Froyo and Eclair

Have tried extending timeouts with

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClientParams,3*60*1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClientParams,3*60*1000);
```

but didn't help.

feels like gingerbread or CM7 has added some sleep low power stuff that screws with me?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, power management was improved in 2.3... it's more aggressive about suspending non-foreground processes while the screen's off.

I suspect you will need to acquire [a partial wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK) for the duration of your network usage.

Comment: No problem. Tag me in a comment if you need anything else with this. FWIW, given the countless times I've woken up to a phone with a dead battery that was at least 40% charged before going to sleep, I think the new OS does the right thing. Please don't abuse the wakelock privilege! :)

Comment: :-) yeah, the danger of consuming battery is high.  mind you, I wouldn't have thought that the OS would screw with an open SSL/TCP connection ...